# Replace character in filename using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following directory I am trying to manipulate in a PowerShell Script:

`C:\Users\winAdmin\Documents\ManagedList1.txt`

Within the script, I want to change the name of the directory from `C:\Users\winAdmin\Documents\ManagedList1.txt` to `C:\Users\winAdmin\Documents\ManagedList2.txt`, effectively replacing the "1" with a "2" at the end of the file name.

What is the best way to go about this with PowerShell?

Comment: `Rename-Item ManagedList1.txt ManagedList2.txt` ?

Comment: That’s quite an odd folder naming convention

Answer (score 0):

To simply change the name of (move) this specific file:

```
Move-Item `
    -Path "C:\Users\winAdmin\Documents\ManagedList1.txt" `
    -Destination "C:\Users\winAdmin\Documents\ManagedList2.txt"
```